# VBA Function Return no Value

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this function. This function is not returning value.

```
Function CalcComm(salesdate As Date, salesamount As Double) As Double

If sales_A < 10000 Then
Commission = salesamount * 0.03
ElseIf salesamount >= 10000 And salesamount < 25000 Then
Commission = salesamount * 0.04
ElseIf salesamount >= 25000 Then
Commission = salesamount * 0.06
Else: Commission = salesamount * 0.06
End If

If month(saledate) = 1 Or month(saledate) = 2 Or month(saledate) = 12 Then
Commission = salesamount * 0.015

End If
End Function
```

Comment: `CalcComm = Commission` before `End Function`

Answer (score 5):

You did not assign the function the value you want to return. e.g. `CalcComm = Commission`.

`sales_A` is not declared and I believe should be `salesamount`, `saledate` is a typo and should be `salesdate`. Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to enforce variable declaration (and indirectly helps you catch typo).

Your code logic could make use of `Select Case` statements, the code below will return:

- 1.5% if in the month of Jan, Feb and Dec;
- For other months

  - 3% for `< 10000`;
  - 4% for `10000-25000` and;
  - 6% for `>= 25000` and above.

```
Option Explicit

Function CalcComm(salesdate As Date, salesamount As Double) As Double
    Dim Commission As Double
    
    Select Case Month(salesdate)
        Case 1, 2, 12: Commission = salesamount * 0.015
        Case Else
            Select Case salesamount
                Case Is < 10000: Commission = salesamount * 0.03
                Case Is < 25000: Commission = salesamount * 0.04
                Case Else: Commission = salesamount * 0.06
            End Select
    End Select
    
    CalcComm = Commission
End Function
```

Comment: Raymond I think the part that checks month might be for adding additional commission for the festive period, after the initial commission has been added.

Comment: @norie If that's the case then his original math is wrong as well.. OP needs to clarify if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not returning the value in the function name, both of the If functions contain errors:

- sales_A isn't a value passed into the function
- saledate should be salesdate

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate Commission (`UDF`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Function CalcComm( _
    ByVal SalesDate As Date, _
    ByVal SalesAmount As Double) _
As Double
    
    Dim CommRate As Double
    
    Select Case SalesAmount
    Case Is < 10000
        CommRate = 0.03
    Case Is < 25000
        CommRate = 0.04
    Case Else
        CommRate = 0.06
    End Select
    
    Select Case Month(SalesDate)
    Case 1, 2, 12
        CommRate = CommRate + 0.015
    End Select
    
    CalcComm = SalesAmount * CommRate

End Function
```